# VBA: Error when savings as CSV: Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: vba, excel, csv

In excel 2016 on Mac, I'm attempting to save an individual sheet as a CSV in excel and I keep getting the

> Run-time error '424': Object required

or

> Run-time error: '1004'

I've searched long and hard, but simply cannot find an appropriate answer/fix:

```
Sub AV_Guest_Macro()
'
' AV_Guest_Macro Macro

    LastRow = Range("aa1").Value
   
   'Copy Formulas
    
    Range("L2:U2").Copy
    Range("L3:U" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
     
    
    RowCheck = 2
    
    Do Until RowCheck > LastRow
    
        'Delete rows that have duplicate emails
        If Range("N" & RowCheck).Value = "Exclude" Then
            Range("X" & RowCheck).EntireRow.Delete
    
            LastRow = LastRow - 1
    
        Else 'this row will be imported
            RowCheck = RowCheck + 1
       
        End If
     
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' ERROR ON THIS LINE
    CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Users").SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\Users\Jhartley416\Desktop\JB_Test\AV_Users_Update_2016" _
        , FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close


    Windows("AB JB Template - JLH2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Users").Activate
    
    Sheets("Users").Range("A4:U10000").ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using an older version of Excel but so maybe something changed but in my version you'd use `ThisWorkbook`  not `CurrentWorkbook`.  I don't see CurrentWorkbook declared anywhere.  Do you have `Option Explicit` on?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reference the selected workbook is ActiveWorkbook instead of CurrentWorkbook:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ "\Users\Jhartley416\Desktop\JB_Test\AV_Users_Update_2016" _ , FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I thought that too but tested it and evidently you can save a worksheet.